# How can I solve 404 Not Found on vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, http-status-code-404, single-page-application, vuex

I use vuex store to send linking several pages in my project

My router like this :

```js
    Vue.use(Router)

    export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home
        },
        {
          path: '/search-result',
          name: 'search-result',
          component: SearchResult
        },
        {
          path: '/detail',
          name: 'detail',
          component: Detail
        }
      ]
    })
```

In my main.js, I add like this :

```js
    new Vue({
      created () {
        let self = this
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          if (self.$route.path === '/detail' || self.$route.path === '/search-result') {
            e = e || window.event
            // old browsers
            if (e) { e.returnValue = 'Changes you made may not be saved' }
            // safari, chrome(chrome ignores text)
            return 'Changes you made may not be saved'
          } else {
            return null
          }
        }
        if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
          if (this.$route.path === '/detail' || self.$route.path === '/search-result') {
            this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
          } else {
            console.log('reload page without redirect')
          }
        }
      },
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
```

So if user refresh, it will back to home page

In my localhost, it works. But on my server production, if I refresh, it exist error like this :

404 Not Found

nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

How can I solve this problem? Do I need SSR implementation to my project that uses SPA?

Comment: Do you have your server configured [correctly](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)?

Comment: @Steven B. Yes of course

Comment: @SuccessMan I noticed a typo in the code above `=== '/earch-result'` , probably should be `=== '/search-result'` .

Comment: @Pascal Lamers. Sorry... Typo

Comment: @Pascal Lamers Do you have a solution?

Comment: @SuccessMan Not directly. If I understand correct, your goal is to whenever the user refreshes the page, he will be redirected to the home page. Right ? But with the code above it only works in localhost but not in production ?

Comment: @Pascal Lamers Yes of course. You are right